# Build Ubuntu removing the unnecessary applications

Tags: 12.04, 10.04

There are many apps in ubuntu like vino, vinagre etc that sit idle on my PC and have no use. Removing these apps does not remove the dependencies and hence take up space. This space is costlier when I have to run the system live for recovery or some other works. Installing apps over the LiveRUN takes up space in RAM Drive. Hence I want to start from the kernel and build up ubuntu (for every LTS version) that will have all the features of the OS but will remove the apps I never need to use along with their dependencies, Hence providing me a light distro customized for me entirely.

I have previously heard of MinimalCD for Ubuntu but have never used. Is that what is to be used for this kind of a project?

Comment: I have tried Remastersys with drastic results. please avoid that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Removing these apps does not remove the dependencies and hence take up space.

By running `apt-get purge <packagename>` you remove a package including is configuration files and following this by a `apt-get autoremove` will completely remove all unused dependencies of your system.

While you might have some fun in building your own distro, it will definitely be more work than simply removing the dependencies you don't need.

You have to ask yourself, if your final system will be closer to a linux kernel (then start from there and add the software you need, lots of work), or if your final system is closer to Ubuntu (then start from there and remove packages + dependencies).

Comment: nice comment there on the desired resulting OS, great answer.

Comment: Its better to start from the kernel. As there will be more things to learn I hope. But at the end of the day i want to close up on ubuntu with only the necessary packages along with their depencies. and hoping to keep the distro as small as possible.